# How to display arrow (link) labels in custom street view panorama?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, panoramas

I know that this is probably going to be a simple answer and I'm going to come out looking less than intelligent but I've been searching for hours now and can not find a clear answer.

I have build the below custom panorama tour using street view and I want to display the link description above the arrows to help the user know where they are going. I have specified a description for every link but it does not display over the arrow.

I have set the linksControl: true but on the arrow shows up.

```
function initPano() {
    var panorama1 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
        pano: 'reception',
        visible: true,
        linksControl: true,
        panoProvider: getCustomPanorama
    }); 
  }
```

Here's the tour: https://jsfiddle.net/e9g1L7nr/2/

Any help would be amazing as at this point I am completely stuck :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found the solution?